# How to add multiple images to to custom table view cell in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, swift3

I have an imageView in my custom table view cell. I have multiple images copied to Xcode.
Now I need to display these images in the tableview cell. I have decalared a `leaderImage` variable in which I have given the image names.

How can I achieve this?

---

This is what I have:

```
var leaderImage : [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {

  self.leadername = ["Oomen Chandy","PC.George","Veena George","M.Mukesh"]
  self.areaName = ["Puthupally","Poonjar","Thrissur","Kollam"]
  self.approvalrate = ["98%","94%","88%","95%"]
    self.leaderImage = ["rahul","Anil","Manu",]

    leadTableSetup()
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func leadTableSetup(){

    LeadTableView.delegate = self
    LeadTableView.dataSource = self

    self.LeadTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "LeaderBoardTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "leadCell")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return leadername.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
    cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row]
    cell.areaLbl.text = areaName[indexPath.row]
    cell.approvalLabel.text = approvalrate[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView = leaderImage[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell `cellForRowAt` method

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: leaderImage[indexPath.row])
```

In your `self.leadername` contains 5 element but rest of all your array contains 4 or 3 element that's why you have problem occur.

**To avoid Crash**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return leaderImage.count

}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot